# How to have multiple buttons calling same JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, multiple-instances

I'm wondering why the first button works and the last three buttons don't in this problem I am having.

http://jsfiddle.net/j4c7U/387/

It would be great if I could get any pointers in where I am going wrong and how I can fix it.

Thanks

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("LearnMoreBtn").onclick = function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
};

  document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";      
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
    Popup contents here
    <button id="CloseBtn">ClosePopup</button>
</div>
<div>
some other content that will be behind the popup
</div><button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
    Popup contents here
     <button id="CloseBtn">ClosePopup</button>
</div>
<div>
    some other content that will be behind the popup
</div><button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
    Popup contents here
    <button id="CloseBtn">ClosePopup</button>
</div>
<div>
some other content that will be behind the popup
</div><button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
Popup contents here
<button id="CloseBtn">ClosePopup</button>
</div>
<div>
some other content that will be behind the popup
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
display:none;    
position:fixed;  
left:0px;        
top:0px;         
width:100%;      
height:100%;     
background:#000; 
opacity:0.5;     
z-index:99999;   
}

#popup {
display:none;
position:fixed;
left:50%;        
top:50%;         
width:300px;     
height:150px;
margin-top:-75px;
margin-left:-150px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #000;
z-index:100000;      
}
```

Comment: don't use element id. instead use class

Comment: IDs must be unique, CLASSes can be repeated.

Answer (score 3):

The `id` attribute must be unique, so you can't have more than one of each id.  I would recommend using the `class` attribute instead with `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsById`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are using the same ID for every tag(same id for each button,div,etc.)to fix this you could use classes instead of IDs or have the event triggers in the HTML tags and add names to the js functions, like so:

html:

```
<button onclick="popup1()"></button>

<button onclick="popup2()"></button>
```

js:

```
function popup1() {

//add whatever you need here

}

function popup2() {

//add whatever you need here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give your buttons (or any other elements) the same ID
You can either give them unique IDs and target them individually or you can use querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName. These methods will return a nodelist you can loop through and assign the click events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName